# Kleisli flatMap stange type parameter subtyping

Tags: scala, scala-cats

can someone clarify to me why the signature of flatMap for Kelisli in cats is as follow:

```
def flatMap[C, AA <: A](f: B => Kleisli[F, AA, C])(implicit F: FlatMap[F]): Kleisli[F, AA, C] =
    Kleisli.shift(a => F.flatMap[B, C](run(a))((b: B) => f(b).run(a)))
```

What i actually do not understand well is `AA <: A`  Why AA must be a subType of A ?

I get the Kleisli flatmap operation, it is the subTyping i do not get?

Comment: It is actually contravariant -A

Comment: It was changed recently

Comment: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/2749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can and it makes life easier sometimes.

Suppose we have some subtypes

```
trait Animal {
  def makeNoise: IO[Unit]
}

case class DogFood(label: String)

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal {
  def makeNoise = IO.println(s"$name says Woof!")
  def consumeEdibles(df: DogFood) = IO.println(s"$name ate '${df.label}'. Yum!")
}
```

And we can make few Kleislis:

```
val doNoise = Kleisli((_: Animal).makeNoise)
val eatNewFood = Kleisli((_: Dog).consumeEdibles(new DogFood("Fancy Dog Food")))
```

Notice that first of them only requires an `Animal`, but both of them can be called with a `Dog`. It sounds reasonable that we would be able to somehow compose the two into a single Kleisli that can be called with a dog. Right? Let's try it.

---

It just works if you start with a Dog Kleisli:

```
// Both valid - contravariance makes it so that doNoise : Kleisli[IO, Animal, Unit]
// extends Kleisli[IO, Dog, Unit] and compiler figures it out. Result is Kleisli[IO, Dog, Unit]
eatNewFood.flatMap(_ => doNoise)
(eatNewFood >> doNoise)
```

---

But notice how you can't do this:

```
(doNoise >> eatNewFood)
```

That's because `>>` is "stupid". Since you start with a `Kleisli[IO, Animal, Unit]`, it requires the next one to also be a `Kleisli[IO, Animal, something]`.

We can rectify it, though, by telling compiler to widen the Kleisli before inferring the type for `>>`:

`((doNoise: Kleisli[IO, Dog, Unit]) >> eatNewFood)`

This is verbose and ugly. Would be nice if we could tell "hey, instead of requiring right hand side to be of a broader type, allow the result to be of a narrower type that is valid for both".

---

And that's exactly what that `flatMap` signature says. Subtyping implies that the narrower type AA can be used in place of a wider type A for left hand side and right hand side as well.

```
// Valid because of this trick you're asking about
// Here AA = Dog <: Animal = A
// Result value is Kleisli[F, AA, C] which resolves to Kleisli[IO, Dog, Unit]
doNoise.flatMap(_ => eatNewFood)
```

All we have lost are some type ascriptions for narrowing the input, and nobody likes those.

Notice that AA and A being same satisfies AA <: A. So while it doesn't *have* to be a different subtype, it *can* and it's both legal and make sense (can call both with a Dog => can compose them into something that can be called with a Dog).

Comment: Thank you for this. Will test it and get back